# How can I load reversely On JMeter in Non-GUI

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter in Non-GUI environment.

I am increasing load now, e.g. 1...5000, but I want to decrease load gradually, e.g. 5000...1

Is it possible?

I can't use GUI env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is going for [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) plugins, for example:

1. [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups)

   [image]
2. [Stepping Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/)

   [image]

You can install these Thread Groups as a part of `Custom Thread Groups` bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

Alternatively you can also use [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) to introduce ramp-down logic, however it will be mostly dependent on your application response time

[image]

More information on above approaches: [How to Ramp Down in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-ramp-down-on-jmeter)